# debug is not working propely after upgrading Preact version

Tags: javascript, debugging, webpack, preact

i have some kind of problem in debugging my preact project, most of the js errors are nor showing up in the console.

for example i added this code to my component:

```
<button onClick={() => {
  const someVar = someUnknownVariable;
}}>
  fire error
</button>
```

and when i click on the button there is no error showing up in the says that someUnknownVariable is not defined, other js errors are not showing up too.

here is my preact.config.js file:

```
import compose from 'lodash.compose';
export default (config, env, helpers) => {
  return compose(addEmotionPlugin, configRules)(config, env, helpers);
};
function addEmotionPlugin(config) {
  let babel = config.module.rules.filter(loader => loader.loader === 'babel-loader')[0]
    .options;
  babel.plugins.push([
    'emotion',
    {
      hoist: true,
      sourceMap: false,
      autoLabel: true,
      labelFormat: '[local]',
      extractStatic: false,
      outputDir: '',
    },
  ]);
  return config;
}
function configRules(config, env) {
  if (env.isProd) {
    config.devtool = 'source-map';
    config.output.filename = '[name].js';
    config.output.publicPath = process.env.NODE_ASSETS || '/';
  }
  return config;
}
```

and in my index.js file i have this code at the beginning.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV==='development') {
  require("preact/debug");
}
```

this happened after i upgraded preact version, any help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was from an old eventListener on errors `window.addEventListener('error', function(event) {});` causing preact debugging issues, when i removed it the problem solved